# Convert date to new field (datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to convert from string containing `YYYYDD` to a new column of type `Datetime`. Current date only have `YYYYDD` example `200908`. I want to change to `YYYYMMDD` such as `20090829`

My code:

```
with cts as
(
    select TRY_CONVERT(datetime,CRSE_EDTE,112) dte,
          [new_CRSE_EDTE]+'28' newdte 
    from [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
)
update cts 
set newdte = dte
```

Error:

> Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Update or insert of view or function 'cts' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Comment: i think you need to alter the field, is it varchar(6) by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is very clear: the problem is that you're trying to update the `newdte` field defined in the CTE as this expression: `[new_CRSE_EDTE]+'28'`. Obviously, there is no way to update such expression.

You have to modify the CTE to include the field from the base table that you want to update, and update that field on the `UPDATE` query.

perhaps whatyou was trying to do was this:

```
with cts as
(
   select TRY_CONVERT(datetime,CRSE_EDTE,112) dte,
         [new_CRSE_EDTE] newdte 
   from [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
)
update cts 
set newdte = dte + '28'
```

or

```
with cts as
(
   select TRY_CONVERT(datetime,CRSE_EDTE,112) + '28' dte,
         [new_CRSE_EDTE] newdte 
   from [SMBM_DBPELJ].[DBPELJ].[MSTUMASTER]
)
update cts 
set newdte = dte
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Can you write the code for me?

Comment: Can't you see the two different blocks of code that I wrote for you? I fthey don't match what you want to do, please, add more info on the table structure, the original field name, the destination field name, and what transformation you want to do on the data.

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Please, add sample data and the column data types. You can expect us to magically guess how your table and data looks like, and build a correct query.

Comment: Sample data CRSE_EDTE char(7)
Sample data:
1) 199001
2) 199108
3) 199103
4) 200001

Comment: Please, update your question and add all the affected column data types, and some sample of the data which is inside those columns. I think it's very clear what is needed to help you. If you don't do so, I'll vote for closing this question